# Access denied for user 'diduser'@'localhost' to database 'diddata' (1044, 42000)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup a MySQL server and when I went to create a second user it wouldn't give it permissions for the database. I can connect fine as long as I don't specify a database.

> Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'diddata'

The connection details are:

```
{ 'host' : 'localhost', 'user' : 'user', 'password' : 'password' , 'database': 'diddata' };
```

And to create the DB and table I did:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT exists diddata;
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON user.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Note that I've changed the username and password in this question.

I've already checked the privileges in MySQL workbench and they are there.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

```
GRANT ALL ON user.*  << this should be diddata.
```

I noticed it when I went to change the database name in the question.